# Find a url in a document using regex in ruby

Tags: ruby, httparty

I have been trying to find a url in a html document and this has to be done in regex since the url is not in any html tag so I can't use `nokogiri` for that. To get the html i used `httparty` and i did it this way

```
require 'httparty'
doc = HTTParty.get("http://127.0.0.1:4040")
puts doc
```

That outputs the html code. And to get the url i used the `.split()` method to reach to the url. The full code is

```
require 'httparty'

doc = HTTParty.get('http://127.0.0.1:4040').split(".ngrok.io")[0].split('https:')[2]

puts "https:#{doc}.ngrok.io"
```

I wanted to do this using regex since ngrok might update their localhost html file and so this code won't work anymore. How do i do it?

Comment: *"the url is not in any html tag"* -- Nonsense, of course it's in an HTML tag, otherwise the thing you're fetching isn't valid HTML!!! Perhaps you mean it's somewhere in the middle of the `<body>` not at a specific well-defined location like `<div class="some-identifier">`, which is fair enough, but your problem description is misleading.

Comment: Now, we obviously have **ABSOLUTELY NO IDEA** what `http://127.0.0.1:4040` renders on hour machine. So we cannot possibly know if your solution works, or have confidence in providing a recommended alternative/improvement. You need to give more information.

Comment: It sounds like what you actually want to do is `grep` the HTTP body for  something like `%r{https://\w+\.ngrok\.io}`? Because your current code is flawed in that `.split('https:')[2]` very naively assumes there are precisely 2 URLs mentioned somewhere on the page before the `ngrok.io` URL?

Comment: actually. http://localhost:4040 is a ngrok local server configuration. I just said it's a  ngrok localhost webpage. But i like your answer

Comment: "ngrok localhost webpage" is not a very precise description. Does it depend on the version, or configuration? Is there a way I could completely reproduce your problem, **without** needing to go ahead and download/install ngrok myself?? I would strongly advise sharing the actual HTML in your question. That way anyone reading this could have easily, unambiguously, run your code to get the same result.

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to use nokogiri?

Comment: Because i am still new to ruby and i didn't find any way that nokogiri could do that. Maybe it can but i don't know about it. You might want to show me how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly you want to find all hostnames matching "https://(any subdomain).ngrok.io", right ?

If then you want to use [String#scan](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.2/String.html#method-i-scan) with a regexp. Here is an example:

```
# get your body (replace with your HTTP request)
body = "my doc contains https://subdomain.ngrok.io and https://subdomain-1.subdomain.ngrok.io"
puts body

# Use scan and you're done
urls = body.scan(%r{https://[0-9A-Za-z-\.]+\.ngrok\.io})
puts urls
```

It will result in an array containing `["https://subdomain.ngrok.io", "https://subdomain-1.subdomain.ngrok.io"]`

Call `.uniq` if you want to get rid of duplicates

This doesn't handle ALL edge cases but it's probably enough for what you need